# Check the result

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I don't get the same answer that my teacher can you help me?

The density function :
$$f(x):=Cxe^{-x/2} \text{ and } f(0):=0$$

I try to calculate the $C$ constant.
$$1 = C \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x/2} \; dx = C \int_{0}^{\infty} 2u e^{-u} \;2du = 4C \int_{0}^{\infty} ue^{-u} \; du$$

Integration by parts,
$$4C \int_{0}^{\infty} ue^{-u} \; du = 4C \left( \left[-ue^{-u} \right]_0^{\infty} - \left[ e^{-u} \right]_0^{\infty}\right)$$
That where all things go wrong. I my mind, this result to $C=0$ by the answer is $C=1/4$. Can you explain to me how?

Comment: Note that $e^{-u}$ evaluated at $0$ is $1$ (last part of your last displayed formula).  So the integral is $4C$.

Comment: But the first term is equal to $0$ so we get $(0-1)=-1$?

Comment: There is a minus sign in front. So we get $-(0-1)$, which is $1$.

Comment: So stupid. Thanks you!

Comment: You are welcome. And I am sure that I have made altogether many more minus sign errors than you.

Comment: Haven't we all?